# Data is not inserting in the specified column

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a class Vehicle is the **Parent Class** and Two Wheeler and Four Wheeler are the  **Child Classes** that extends parent class.
The problem is when I'm inserting data to my **rto(id,name,vehicle_type,steeringHandle,steeringWheel)** table in database it is inserting the assigned data for the **TwoWheeler** but for **FourWheeler** it is inserting the data  for the method present in Parent Class but when I'm calling a method from child class**(FourWheeler(setsteeringWheel))**  it's not updating the specified data in the 
 steeringWheel column. I'm adding the screen shot of my table.

**Vehicle Class**
`

```
package hibernate_discriminator;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Vehicle(){

    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


}
```

**TwoWheeler Class**

```
`package hibernate_discriminator;


public class TwoWheeler extends Vehicle{

    private String steeringHandle;

    public TwoWheeler(){

    }

    public void setsteeringHandle(String handle){
        this.steeringHandle= handle;
    }

    public String getsteeringHandle(){
        return steeringHandle;
    }


}
`
```

**FourWheeler Class**

```
package hibernate_discriminator;


public class FourWheeler extends Vehicle {

    private String steeringWheel;

    public FourWheeler(){

    }

    public void setsteeringWheel(String wheel){
        this.steeringWheel= steeringWheel;
    }

    public String getsteeringWheel(){
        return steeringWheel;
    }


}
```

**Mapping File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate_discriminator.Vehicle" table="rto" discriminator-value="vehicle">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>

        <discriminator column="vehicle_type" type="string"></discriminator>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"></property>

        <subclass name="hibernate_discriminator.TwoWheeler" extends="Vehicle" discriminator-value="Bike">
            <property name="steeringHandle" column="steeringHandle" type="string"></property>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="hibernate_discriminator.FourWheeler" extends="Vehicle" discriminator-value="Car">
            <property name="steeringWheel" column="steeringWheel" type="string"></property>
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Configuration file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ankita</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <mapping resource="resources/Vehicle.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Main Class**

```
   public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/resources/Config.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf= cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s= sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx= s.beginTransaction();

        Vehicle v= new Vehicle();
        v.setName("Vehicle");

        TwoWheeler tw= new TwoWheeler();
        tw.setName("CBR");
        tw.setsteeringHandle("CBR Handle");

        FourWheeler fw= new FourWheeler();
        fw.setName("Audi A4");
        fw.setsteeringWheel("Audi a7 Wheel");

        s.save(v);
        s.save(tw);
        s.save(fw);
        s.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Adding my database scrrenshot
[image: Database Table]

**FourWheeler Class**

```
   public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/resources/Config.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf= cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s= sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx= s.beginTransaction();

        Vehicle v= new Vehicle();
        v.setName("Vehicle");

        TwoWheeler tw= new TwoWheeler();
        tw.setName("CBR");
        tw.setsteeringHandle("CBR Handle");

        FourWheeler fw= new FourWheeler();
        fw.setName("Audi A4");
        fw.setsteeringWheel("Audi a7 Wheel");

        s.save(v);
        s.save(tw);
        s.save(fw);
        s.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is here...

```
public void setsteeringWheel(String wheel){
    this.steeringWheel= steeringWheel;
}
```

The method parameter is `wheel`, but you're assigning the value of `steeringWheel`.  (You're assigning `this.steeringWheel = steeringWheel`, which means it will have the same value -- `null` -- after the call to `setsteeringWheel()`.)

Comment: TwoWheeler appears to use `this.steeringHandle= handle` where `handle` is (properly) the name of the method parameter.

Comment: Thanks drew for the great response it's worked my silly mistake

Comment: Well pointed out (y), but @Stone be aware that your getter and setter aren't well implemented, they should follow naming convention, You used `setsteeringWheel()` and `getsteeringWheel()`, you need to use and uppercase for the first letter of the attribute name so they need to be `setSteeringWheel()` and `getSteeringWheel()`.

Comment: copy that yes it must be followed from now

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
public void setsteeringWheel(String wheel){
        this.steeringWheel= steeringWheel;
    }
```

You are not using the passed parameter
       this.steeringWheel= wheel;